# Cycling an external file adding each line into a command as a varable

Tags: loops, for-loop, variables

Im trying to use an external file which has a number of lines, using each line as a variable and completing a simple command in bash and saving into multiple external files.

For example, my file commands.txt has :

Group1="Football" 
Group2="Cricket" 
Group3="Squash"

and I want to run the following commands :

grep 'group-title="$Group1' -B 1 'commands.txt' > Football.txt 
grep 'group-title="$Group2' -B 1 'commands.txt' > Cricket.txt 
grep 'group-title="$Group3' -B 1 'commands.txt' > Squash.txt

I assume I can use a for loop to ensure all the lines are used and executed but I cant work out how to use the varable itself and cycle through each line.

John.